# Locking computer drive using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, locking, vb.net-2010

I want to create a project through which I should be able to first see my drives and then select one of them to programically lock them.
Is it possible ?
If so please answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get your devices with `DriveInfo.GetDrives()`.

How do you want to lock them? If you want to encode a folder, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302028/3905529

To lock a device or folder withouth encrypting is not reliable because in this case the data are not locked at another pc.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback...... But my project is to lock the my computer's drive.......... either using encryption, denying access or anything.. it should be able to work even after run time

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code below extracted from http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-Lock-And-Unlock-a-Folder-through-Code-in-VBNET-2310.php. First you have to provide a way to choose the directory you want to lock, in the case shown, a folderbrowserdialog was used.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
        Try
            If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Then I created two buttons to lock and unlock the directory whose path was written in a textbox previously by the function above.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLock.Click
    Dim fs As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(TextBox1.Text)

    fs.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))

    File.SetAccessControl(TextBox1.Text, fs)
End Sub

Private Sub btnUnlock_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUnlock.Click
        Dim fs As FileSystemSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(TextBox1.Text)

        fs.RemoveAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny))

        File.SetAccessControl(TextBox1.Text, fs)
End Sub
```

The first one locks the directory and the other unlocks it.